# Spark load data from s3a on a custom endpoint gets stalled

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, aws-snowball

I am trying to do a simple operation on a spark cluster, by simply running in `pyspark --master yarn` the following code:

```py
op = spark.read.format("csv")
op = op.options(header=True, sep=";")
# This is actually a custom S3 endpoint on a AWS Snowball Edge device
op = op.load("s3a://some-bucket/some/path/file_*.txt")
```

No errors show, but the operation does not complete. Also if I pass an inexistent path in S3 it will throw an error saying the path does not exist. If I try to read from HDFS it will work. So it seems it is communication issue with S3 on reading data.

Here are the details of my stack:

```yaml
spark: https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.2.1/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
awscli: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip
hadoop: https://dlcdn.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.3.1/hadoop-3.3.1.tar.gz
hive: https://dlcdn.apache.org/hive/hive-3.1.2/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin.tar.gz
hadoop_aws: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.3.1/hadoop-aws-3.3.1.jar
aws_java_sdk_bundle: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.874/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.874.jar
```

My core-site.xml

```xml
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://34.223.14.233:9000</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
    <value>http://172.16.100.1:8080</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>foo</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>bar</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.connection.maximum</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Any ideias on troubleshooting this issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to look at the Spark/YARN UI to see if your resource request is too large for the cluster to process

Comment: For the sake of testing I used a file with 1Mb so the issue seems not to be about size

Comment: Files don't matter. Spark executor heap size and total executors is the more important problem... Second problem would be if YARN resource managers are actually running. It's also , unclear why your s3a endpoint is using an HTTP path and an IP address. Are you using something like Minio?

Comment: I think all is running adequately because if I use hdfs:// there are no issues at all. I am running the cluster inside a [Snowball Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/developer-guide/specifications.html#specs-compute-optimized) device which provide S3 and EC2. There is no need for HTTPS as all communication happens inside a private dedicated on-prem network.

Comment: I was just confused why your S3 endpoint was using an IP. I've never used a snowball/edge device personally. In any case, you still need to consult the Spark/YARN UI pages, like I said. Please [edit] with a screenshot of both for your specific app

Comment: that endpoint option is wrong. look at the s3a docs, and also look at the properties to switch ports and disable https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up here when investigating a similar problem. I also had s3a on a custom endpoint stalling (i.e. freezing or hanging). However, my setup is different – I set `HadoopConf` in code instead of a configuration XML.

*The order of config setting statements in code is relevant:* Setting `fs.s3a.endpoint` has to be first, and only after that `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` can be set. What lead me to this solution was that I logged all hadoop conf values and noticed that `fs.s3a.endpoint` was empty.